# How to discover which software fires AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload?

Tags: c#, iis-8, domainunload

How to discover which software fires AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload?
I've an app running a long task on IIS 8 and I suspect some software is firing the above event by changing files permissions. There is not anti-virus software installed. But we have Nagios Client, New Relic and OCS (software for inventory).

Comment: DomainUnload is fired by the CLR.  That could be because another thread call AppDomain.Unload but the more common "why did this happen??" cause is asp.net restarting the appdomain.  Could be as simple as editing web.config or a change in the bin directory.  [Read this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/433194).

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah. I suspect some sort of monitor system change permissions, or perhaps another properties, for files like web.config and bin directory. The link you provided is very useful and I'll try to aply to my solution. Maybe better luck with that. Thank you!